# How to apply function to a chosen region only?

Tags: routes, theming

I am using this template.php function:

```
function mytheme_menu_tree($variables) {
    return '<ul class="page_nav" id="pages">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

Now it applies to the menu no matter in which region it is. What if I want it to apply only if the menu is inside i.e. Top Menu region? I guess its something that needs to be added before *return* line?

Also I noticed another problem. It applies to all menus, i.e. if I have two menus, my *return* line applies to both menus, and 2nd menu is not even shown because id="" can be shown only once.

So I need that function to apply to the menu which is in Top menu region only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`theme_menu_tree__MENU_NAME()`](http://drupal.org/node/254940#theme-suggestions-for-menus) to target a specific menu.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot predict what menus the users will be creating and using.